# Wrong Visual Studio version launched by Dell Instant Launch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dell-xps, version

I have a Dell XPS L702X laptop.

To the right of the power button is a touch sensitive button called "Dell Instant Launch".

I have had this configured to open Visual Studio 2010 for a while but I just installed SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition.  Now when I use "Dell Instant Launch" it opens Visual Studio 2008 shell rather than VS 2010.

This is the path I have assigned to "Dell Instant Launch" for the "Launch A Program" option:  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`

Any ideas why devenv.exe is not launching the VS2010 shell or where I would look to fix this?

Comment: Is this a factory Dell install of the OS or have you re-installed the OS using non Dell recovery media?

Comment: It's a factory install.  Instant Launch Manager is an item in Windows Mobility Center in a section entitled Customized by Dell Inc.

Comment: Unfortunately Dell does not have much documentation about this feature that I can find, I would have a look in the bios to see if there is something related in there, does it work for other applications?

Comment: As described above it was working fine until I recently installed SQL Server 2008 Dev Ed.  I expect that installing SQL is the origin of the problem rather than Dell or the OS, I'm just not sure where to look to correct the anomalous behaviour.  I figured someone with expert Visual Studio knowledge might be able to suggest something.

Comment: You might edit your question title to reflect Visual Studio, to get more attention.